# Print on debian like on Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: debian, ubuntu, printing

I have been using Ubuntu & Linux Mint for quite a while. I now switched to debian. I'm very happy with this except for printing.

I just can't find any solution besides using CUPS on the web, which every time I tried to set up I failed.

Ain't there any utility that could be installed on Debian that would make adding a printer plug & play just like it works on Ubuntu/Mint?

I can't believe this is such a complicated task for such a popular OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found [this](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html) utility specific to my printer.

Works really well though it is not plug&play.

Comment: And it's packaged in Debian as [`hplip`](https://tracker.debian.org/hplip).